# Create database using Firebird API is failing

Tags: api, firebird2.5

This is my source code sample inspired by code samples that are part of Firebird installation directory (C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\examples):

```
AnsiString db_path = MainForm->exeFilePath + "\\results.fdb"; // C:\Projects\DBX\bin\results.fdb
if (FileExists(db_path))
{
    return;
}

HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary(L"fbclient.dll");
if (dll == NULL)
{
    throw Exception(L"Failed to load Firebird client library FBCLIENT.DLL!\r\nApplication will exit now.");
}

Pisc_dsql_execute_immediate pisc_dsql_execute_immediate = (Pisc_dsql_execute_immediate)GetProcAddress(dll, "isc_dsql_execute_immediate");
if (pisc_dsql_execute_immediate == NULL)
{
    throw Exception(L"Failed to load 'isc_dsql_execute_immediate' entry point in FBCLIENT.DLL. It seems like Firebird installation is corrupted. "
    "Contact system administrator.\r\nApplication will exit now.");
}

Pisc_commit_transaction pisc_commit_transaction = (Pisc_commit_transaction)GetProcAddress(dll, "isc_commit_transaction");
if (pisc_commit_transaction == NULL)
{
    throw Exception(L"Failed to load 'isc_commit_transaction' entry point in FBCLIENT.DLL. It seems like Firebird installation is corrupted. "
    "Contact system administrator.\r\nApplication will exit now.");
}

Pisc_detach_database pisc_detach_database = (Pisc_detach_database)GetProcAddress(dll, "isc_detach_database");
if (pisc_detach_database == NULL)
{
    throw Exception(L"Failed to load 'isc_detach_database' entry point in FBCLIENT.DLL. It seems like Firebird installation is corrupted. "
    "Contact system administrator.\r\nApplication will exit now.");
}

Pisc_sqlcode pisc_sqlcode = (Pisc_sqlcode)GetProcAddress(dll, "isc_sqlcode");
if (pisc_sqlcode == NULL)
{
    throw Exception(L"Failed to load 'isc_sqlcode' entry point in FBCLIENT.DLL. It seems like Firebird installation is corrupted. "
    "Contact system administrator.\r\nApplication will exit now.");
}

ISC_STATUS_ARRAY status;               /* status vector */
isc_db_handle   newdb = NULL;          /* database handle */
isc_tr_handle   trans = NULL;          /* transaction handle */
AnsiString create_db;
create_db.printf("CREATE DATABASE '%s'", db_path.c_str());
long sqlcode;
UnicodeString msg;

if (pisc_dsql_execute_immediate(status, &newdb, &trans, 0, create_db.c_str(), 1, NULL))
{
    // ERROR OCCURRES HERE
    sqlcode = pisc_sqlcode(status);
    msg.printf(L"Operation 'CREATE DATABASE' failed with sqlcode %ld.\r\nApplication will exit now.", sqlcode);
    throw Exception(msg.c_str());
}

pisc_commit_transaction(status, &trans);
pisc_detach_database(status, &newdb);

FreeLibrary(dll);
dll = NULL;
```

Database creation is failing with sql code -902. The directory 'C:\Projects\DBX\bin\' exists and doesn't contain file named 'results.fdb'. Whats the reason for error behaviour and how can I avoid it? Is there somewhere detailed description of Firebird API?

Comment: I think you can succeed if you call directly the isc_create_database, since I'm not sure if the create database statement is supported via execute_immediate.

Comment: @jachguate execute immediate would work, but you need to be connected to the server first; I believe this also applies to isc_create_database. BTW: sqlcode -902 is not really helpful (as it covers a large domain of errors), it would be better to get the gds errorcode

Comment: @Mark you may be right, feel free to post that as an answer, but this looks like an abandoned question, since the OP never came back to provide feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I forgot were user credentials. See updated code sample (excerpt):

```
ISC_STATUS_ARRAY status;               /* status vector */
isc_db_handle   newdb = NULL;          /* database handle */
isc_tr_handle   trans = NULL;          /* transaction handle */
AnsiString create_db;
create_db.printf("CREATE DATABASE '%s' USER '%S' PASSWORD '%S'", db_path.c_str(), MainForm->currentUser.name, MainForm->currentUser.password);
long sqlcode;
UnicodeString msg;

if (pisc_dsql_execute_immediate(status, &newdb, &trans, 0, create_db.c_str(), 1, NULL))
{
    sqlcode = pisc_sqlcode(status);
    msg.printf(L"Operation 'CREATE DATABASE' failed with sqlcode %ld.\r\nApplication will exit now.", sqlcode);
    throw Exception(msg.c_str());
}
```